# Наименование колонок mysql для передачи в переменную

Tags: php, mysql

В базе mysql таблицы (categories, products) имеют несколько колонок с одинаковыми названиями id, title. При сложном запросе из обоих таблиц

```
"select * from products join categories on products.parent=categories.id order by products.parent ASC"
```

и последующей передаче значений переменной

```
        <td><?=$row['parent']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['title']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['price']?></td>
```

есть непонимание, что собственно туда будет передано. Можно ли конкретизировать значение в квадратных скобках по типу products.title либо использования ковычек, фигурных скобок и т.д.
Или единственное решение это сделать все названия столбцов уникальными.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно задать псевдонимы для выводимых данных, например

```
SELECT name as what_is_this FROM table
            ^^---- ключевое слово
```

При таком подходе на выходе будет  `what_is_this` а не `name`.

Да, в таком случае надо будет перечислять колонки в `SELECT` явно. Однако стОит заметить, что общая практика в построении запросов именно **явное перечисление желаемых столбцов**, а использование звёздочки, скорее, моветон (да, инооооогда можно, есть случае когда можно и удобнее, но всё же лучше привыкать к явному перечислению).

---

Ещё можно задать алиас для таблиц

```
SELECT t1.name as t1_name, t2.name as t2_name
FROM table1 t1  
JOIN table2 t2
USING(id)
```

`t1` и `t2` - псевдонимы для таблиц и можно в других участках запроса обращаться по ним. Это удобно, т.к. не нужно писать наименование таблицы целиком например. Особенно если название таблицы например `control_system_equipment`

Comment: Спасибо! Вариант с 'AS' это именно то, что нужно

Comment: @InDevX полагаю что опечатка и должно быть `t2.name as t2_name`

Comment: @InDevX "t2.name as t2.name в чем смысл?" --- очепятка. Ну видно же)  я то изменил, но вы могли и сами поправить ;-)

Comment: @morbo если ответ Вам помог, можете принять его, нажав слева на галочку.

[АлексейШиманский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%a8%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9) не часто в чужие ответы лезу)